# How to make Valgrind debugger step through a program

Tags: c++, valgrind

Good morning, I am trying to use the Valgrind debugger to step through a program.

My valgrind command line is `valgrind -tool memcheck --leak-check=full --db-enable=yes ./MatchUpAcurate.exe.`

I am using valgrind-3.5.0 on Centos Linux release 5.5 with gdb version 7,0.1-23.el5_5.2.

I enter Yes when valgrind asks the question Attach to Debugger. Then, the valgrind debugger returns with: `4428: return new tuple2<int,A>(2, i++, p->next());`

When I try to use the gdb step or continue command, valgrind says

`[New Thread 0x410fd10 (LWP 6548] Cannot find user-level thread for LWP 6551: generic error.`

When I try to use `valgrind --single-step=yes` debugger option on the valgrind command-line, valgriind says `Bad option aborting`.

Could any valgrind users show me how  to step through C++ source  code or continue through a program? Thank you.

Comment: I am not using any multithreading in the program I am trying to debug. Thank you.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to debug a 32-bit application on a x86_64 machine? if so, then you might be interested in [this](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9069).

Comment: @diverscuba, Thank you for your reply. I talked to a valgrind developer and the developer told me how to upgrade valgrind 3.5 to a valgrind 3.6.0 debugger.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also get vgdb in the 3.7.0 release. From the release notes:

- GDB server: Valgrind now has an embedded GDB server.  That means it
  is possible to control a Valgrind run from GDB, doing all the usual
  things that GDB can do (single stepping, breakpoints, examining
  data, etc).  Tool-specific functionality is also available.  For
  example, it is possible to query the definedness state of variables
  or memory from within GDB when running Memcheck; arbitrarily large
  memory watchpoints are supported, etc.  To use the GDB server, start
  Valgrind with the flag --vgdb-error=0 and follow the on-screen
  instructions.

There's more info in the valgrind online manual.

Answer (score 13):

I asked the valgrind developers how to create a valgrind debugger. Here is what they said;

1. Download the 3.6.0 source files from the valgrind website.
2. Then you have to apply the patch which is in the bug 214909.
3. Once properly compiled, you launch your application like this:

   ```
   valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 ./prog
   ```

   and then in another window:

   ```
   gdb ./prog
   target remote | vgdb
   ```
4. Do not start an external gdbserver : what the patch does is to integrate a gdbserver inside valgrind.
   This gdbserver integrated inside valgrind is activated by the --vgdb=yes.