# Exception thrown during valgrind execution but not when program is called directly

Tags: gcc, valgrind

I am running in a very odd problem and I understand that it may be hard to diagnose from afar. But any hints would be helpful.

Having said this, here's my problem:

When I run valgrind to execute my program, an exception is thrown. However, when I call the program directly from the shell, it runs fine.

I have tried to use valgrind's vgdb to look into why this exception occurs. But this only allows me to investigate the variables after the exception occurred since I haven't found a good way to start gdb after I attached it to valgrind (without using continue) and step through the code.

I have already tried to recreate just the code segment where the exception is thrown but using the same variable content, I do not trigger the exception.

I should add that I'm doing this on a VMWare Workstation 8.0.1 virtual machine with with Ubuntu 11.10 and gcc 4.6.1, valgrind 3.7.0, gdb 7.3.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe I found the reason for this behavior. It appears that the limit on the largest double is different in `vgdb` and shell. After attempting to calculate 1.2E56^9 inside `vgdb` I receive `nan` whereas when the program is called from the shell, it happily continues (and finds the correct result).

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas:

1. a missing command line-parameter when you invoke your program via valgrind - maybe there's a special way to pass such parameter to your program
2. a different runtime behaviour of your program when it's executed in valgrind. valgrind is a kind of debugger, so maybe threads are scheduled in a different order and parts of your code might run slower. Maybe that triggers a bug like a race condition.

Is it possible to post some of the code here - especially around the location that exception is raised?

Comment: 1) The program doesn't take command line parameters. 2) Basically, the code first parses a function evaluation and then operates on the constructed graph. But, the execution of the code is linear and I suppose that valgrind doesn't change the order in which code executes

Comment: Ok, concerning the debugging in valgrind, there's another thread here on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945586/how-to-make-valgrind-debugger-step-through-a-program

Comment: I did see the thread before which prompted me to try vgdb. But, when I start `valgrind --vgdb=yes -vgdb-error=0 main` and then attached to it inside gdb with `target remote | vgdb`. It switches to that thread but then only displays `0x040010e0 in ?? ()`. The only way for me to start it is with `continue`. So far, I only can stop it with `Cmd+c` in the valgrind shell, but there must be a better way.

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint before you issue the continue command. Therefore, you might have to load your program into gdb first, as you're doing some kind of remote debugging (with the symbol-file or add-symbol-file commands).

Comment: "soo maybe [...] parts of your code might run slower." Hey, this is valgrind. Delete "maybe", "parts" and "might" :)