# Mancala program showing correct output but valgrind showing errors

Tags: c++, arrays, string, valgrind

I had an assignment to replicate mancala. The rules of the game are slightly different from original, and are the following:

> The active player removes all stones from a pit on their side of the board and distributes them counter-clockwise around the board.

> Distribution includes the player's goal, but not the opponent's goal.

> If distribution ends in the player's goal, they take another turn.

> If distribution ends on the player's side, in a previously empty pit, the last stone and any stones immediately across the board are moved to active player's goal (and their turn ends).

> If a player's side of the board is empty (not including their goal), any remaining stones are collected by the opponent and the game is over.

I failed the assignment a while back and I'm still trying to figure out why I'm wrong. The program has correct output but my school requires us to use a programming tool called valgrind and that's where the issue comes from.

Why would valgrind give me this error

```
==5098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5098==    at 0x49ACB33: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:892)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: put (locale_facets.h:2395)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:73)
==5098==    by 0x10948C: Mancala::getBoard[abi:cxx11]() (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098==    by 0x1092B7: main (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098== 
==5098== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5098==    at 0x49AB01B: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:821)
==5098==    by 0x49ACB5E: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:894)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: put (locale_facets.h:2395)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:73)
==5098==    by 0x10948C: Mancala::getBoard[abi:cxx11]() (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098==    by 0x1092B7: main (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098== 
==5098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5098==    at 0x49AB02D: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:824)
==5098==    by 0x49ACB5E: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:894)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: put (locale_facets.h:2395)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:73)
==5098==    by 0x10948C: Mancala::getBoard[abi:cxx11]() (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098==    by 0x1092B7: main (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098== 
==5098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5098==    at 0x49ACB94: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:914)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: put (locale_facets.h:2395)
==5098==    by 0x49BC4FC: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:73)
==5098==    by 0x10948C: Mancala::getBoard[abi:cxx11]() (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098==    by 0x1092B7: main (in /home/oddstap/Documents/2.C++/Projects/malacala/Newest mancala/new/mancala)
==5098==
```

mancala.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Mancala
{
    int gameBoard[14];
    int playerS;
    int getGoal(int p);


    public:
        Mancala();
        std::string getBoard();
        int getPlayer();
        int getScore(int player);
        bool move(int n);
};
```

mancala.cpp

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "mancala.h"

Mancala::Mancala()
{
    playerS = 0;
    for (int i{0}; i < 14; ++i) //set up the intial board
    {
        if (i == 6 || i == 13)
        {
            gameBoard[i] = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            gameBoard[i] = 4;    
        }
    }
}

std::string Mancala::getBoard() //return the gameboard in the correct mancala format
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::right << gameBoard[13];
    ss << " |";
    for (int i{0}; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        ss << std::setw(3) << std::right << gameBoard[12 - i];
    }
    ss << " |";
    if (playerS == 0)
    {
        ss << "  *\n - |";
    }
    else if (playerS == 1)
    {
        ss << "  -\n * |";
    }
    else  
    {
        ss << "  -\n - |";
    }
    for (int j{0}; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        ss << std::setw(3) << std::right << gameBoard[j];
    }
    ss << " |" << std::setw(3) << std::right << gameBoard[6] << "\n";
    return ss.str();
}

int Mancala::getPlayer()
{
    return playerS;
}

int Mancala::getScore(int player)
{
    return gameBoard[getGoal(player)];
}

int Mancala::getGoal(int p)
{
    if (p == 0)
    {
        return 6;
    }
    else  
    {
        return 13;
    }
}

bool Mancala::move(int n)
{
    int pos = getGoal(playerS) - n;
    int current = gameBoard[pos];
    gameBoard[pos] = 0;
    if (current == 0)   //this isn't an allowed move
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i{0}; i < current; ++i)
    {
        pos = (pos + 1) % 14;
        if (playerS == 1 && pos == 6)  //skips other goal 
        {
            ++pos;
        }   
        ++gameBoard[pos];
    }

    int mirror{gameBoard[12 - pos]};

    if (gameBoard[pos] == 1 && playerS == 0 && pos < 6)   
    {
        gameBoard[pos] = 0;
        gameBoard[6] += (mirror + 1);
        gameBoard[12 - pos] = 0;
        playerS = 1 - playerS;
    }
    if (gameBoard[pos] == 1 && playerS == 1 && pos > 6) //tests for player 1
    {
        gameBoard[pos] = 0;
        gameBoard[13] += (1 + mirror);
        gameBoard[12 - pos] = 0;
        playerS = 1 - playerS;
    }
    if (pos != getGoal(playerS))
    {
        playerS = 1 - playerS;  //change turns
    }

    int count{};
    int count1{};
    
    for (int k{0}; k < 6; ++k)  //lines 123-159 test each side of board for a 0. If whole side is 0, other player wins and collects all marbles on their side
    {
        if (gameBoard[k] == 0)
        {
            ++count;
        } else{
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int l{0}; l < 6; ++l)
    {
        if (gameBoard[12 - l] == 0)
        {
            ++count;
        } else{
            count1 = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 6)
    {
        playerS = -1;
        for (int m{0}; m < 6; ++m)
        {
            gameBoard[13] += gameBoard[12 - m];
            gameBoard[12 - m] = 0;
            
        }
    } else if (count1 >= 6){
        playerS = -1;
        for (int z{0}; z < 6; ++z)
        {
            gameBoard[6] += gameBoard[z];
            gameBoard[z] = 0;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "mancala.h"

int main()
{
    Mancala m;
    int moves[] = { 4,1,5,3,2 };
    for (int i:moves){
        m.move(i);
        std::cout << m.getBoard() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add comments on the lines in your code where Valgrind reports the errors (they all seem to be on line `32` in the `mancala3.cpp` file). Is the `mancala.cpp` file you show really the same as `mancala3.cpp` which is in the Valgrind report? If I count correctly, then line 32 is `ss << " |";` which doesn't make much sense. And `main` is supposed to be in the same source file (at line 200), which doesn't match the code you show us. So, are you really showing us the correct source?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My apologies, Valgrind was first ran with main as part of mancala3.cpp which is the same as mancala.cpp above. I have now gone through and reran the compilation with the three file example shown in the question.

Comment: The problem now is that you forgot to build with debug information (the `-g` flag), so Valgrind doesn't report the file-name or line-number.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just ran it with the -g flag and the output is identical, when i compiled i also used the -g flag.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It should show you exactly where the problem is

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using vscode, the program produces correct output but valgrind shows issues. How would i debug?

Comment: The first few google results https://heeris.id.au/2016/valgrind-gdb/ https://indico.cern.ch/event/392796/contributions/1827927/attachments/1196707/1744649/vgdb.pdf https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/11/01/debug-memory-errors-valgrind-and-gdb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945586/how-to-make-valgrind-debugger-step-through-a-program

Comment: You might want to use the GCC built-in *sanitizers* instead. Enabled with an option like `-fsanitize=address,undefined`. Then GCC will add extra code to detect things like out-of-bounds access of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had difficulty myself to find the issue.

The main difficulty was that valgrind effectively found a problem at this line :

```
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::right << gameBoard[13];
```

but this was not the real place where the mistake happens.

It does not happen often (but it happens !), but valgrind missed an out-of-bound access before, in `move(.)` function:

```
    int mirror{gameBoard[12 - pos]};
```

when `pos == 13`.

When valgrind misses to find the place where the error occurs, I generally find difficult (and slow) to use the debugger.
Instead, I found more rapidly the problem by inserting some outputs inside the code.

The problem seems to be solved with:

```
int mirror = 0;
if (pos <= 12) mirror = gameBoard[12 - pos];
```